# Why is my uncorrelated sub-query so slow?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2016

I have a statement which takes **10 seconds** to perform on 10k items in table X:

**Version 1**

```
SELECT * 
FROM X 
WHERE pk = 77843 
  AND (a IS NULL OR a NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(b) 
                              FROM X
                              WHERE pk = 77843
                                AND l IS NOT NULL))
```

The sub-query is uncorrelated, meaning that it has no reference to the outer query. This means the sub-query should only be performed once.

**Version 2:**

Now if I extract the sub-query and perform the computation beforehand the query performs in **< 1s.**

```
DECLARE @listOfb table (id int)

INSERT INTO @listOfb(id) 
    (SELECT DISTINCT(b) as Numbers 
     FROM X
     WHERE pk = 77843
       AND l IS NOT NULL)

SELECT * 
FROM X 
WHERE pk = 77843 
  AND (a IS NULL OR a NOT IN (SELECT * FROM @listOfb))
```

So why is version 2 so much faster than version 1?

**Update**

I have added (what I think is called) an execution plan of Version 1: 
The query is deleting around 10k rows.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the **execution plans** for the two queries?

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function (on a column), it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` and works on the whole selected rows. Remove those redundant parentheses to make things clearer! `SELECT DISTINCT (a), b ...` is better written as `SELECT DISTINCT a, b ...`, but can also be written as `SELECT DISTINCT a, (b) ...`...

Comment: However, no need to do SELECT DISTINCT here...

Comment: @jarlh if I remove the DISTINCT from the Version 2, the query is as slow as version 1

Comment: Doesn't SQL Server optimize better than that?!? Amazing, I shake my head.

Comment: You could try NOT EXISTS instead of Not IN, also I find WHERE clauses with OR's in them often perform better if you change them to be a UNION e.g. SELECT * FROM X WHERE pk = 77943 AND a IS NULL UNION ...

Comment: Probably the statistics on the table are outdated and the wrong execution plan is created. Run a `sp_updatestats` and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions on how to make it faster, but can anybody tell me WHY the sub-query is performed more than once? Because that's how uncorrelated sub-queries should work IMHO and according to the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Try with a Common Table Expression and a UNION:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
   SELECT * 
   FROM X 
   WHERE pk = 77843 
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE a IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM CTE C1
WHERE a IS NOT NULL AND 
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CTE C2 WHERE C1.a = C2.b AND l IS NULL)
```

Comment: There's no need for the first Select, `NOT EXISTS` returns rows with NULLs in `a` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at this [article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg520860.aspx)

I don't have the same server's version but what I would try is to unlock the 'from x' on the main query but also on the sub-query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM X (NOLOCK)
WHERE pk = 77843
```

From my little experience, depends on the table size and the indexes on it, I found sometimes difference of performance while querying twice the same table (especially with same condition 'pk = 77843' and/or updating/deleting operations).

About your last comment. I don't see from the execution plan where the sub-query is performed more than once. In my opinion, the first index_seek  locks the pk column [*main query*] and when arrives the second index_seek [*sub-query*] on the same column (I guess cause I can't see all the details from your screenshot) that cause a performance issue.

But cause of this, you have better performance when you perform this two queries (with almost the same conditions) separately.